# Does "FIFO - Second Chance" Algorithm for page replacement (Memory) is preemptive or non-preemptive?

Tags: algorithm, memory

I personally think that is non-preemptive, because FIFO is by naturally an "atomic" operation. what do you think?

Comment: The term preemptive and non-preemptive is defined for CPU scheduling and not for page replacement algorithms.

Comment: I think at the end this algorithm is an "scheduling algorithm" to schedule the pages, dont you think so?

Comment: Isn't second chance a different algo altogether (than  FIFO). And I agree with sumeet, preemption is not a page replacement term, it is used for CPU scheduling.